# What do the ':!' and '|!' tokens mean in an (Python) Antlr grammar

Tags: python, antlr

I have inherited an old Antlr grammar which is used in a Python program. One of the productions looks like this:

```
merge 
    :! l:expr
        ( n:name_list r:expr 
           { /* do something  with n and r*/ }
          |
           { /* do something else */ }
        )
    |!
        n2:name_list '*' o:expr
           { /* do something with n2 and o */ }
    ;
```

Now, I'm familiar with the `:` and `|` tokens from Yacc and Antlr, but what significance does that extra `!` have, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:! and |! mean to not build AST for the surrounding rules.

Comment: So I should interpret this production as: "if you see an `expr` (calling it `l`), if you then see a `name_list` and another `expr` (calling them `n` and `r`) execute `/* do something with n and r *`/ but _don't_ create an AST for `merge`?

Comment: It still creates the nodes (assigning to labels) if I remember correctly, but doesn't link them into a tree. Your actions must do that.